# How to play sounds correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to run sounds automatically in React. In order to run sounds, I use a non-standard useSound hook. It creates a button and by clicking on this button the sound starts. I made a trigger to automatically start a click and made a delay between sounds.

Sounds come in view of the array. Therefore, I go through the array and create several buttons that should be clicked. Tell me how to create for each button const [play] = useSound("/static/1.mp3"); and your unique id so that all buttons are automatically created and played?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import useSound from "use-sound";

export default function Play(props) {

  const arr = ['./1.mp3', '/static/2.mp3', '/static/3.mp3']

  function Button() {
    return props.newResult.map(() => (
      <button className={styles.buttonPlay} id='button3'>
        {props.newResult}
      </button>
    ));
  }

  const Play = () => {
    const [play] = useSound("/static/1.mp3"); // Буква
    return (
      <>
        <button className={styles.buttonPlay} id='button' onClick={play}>
          Пациент
        </button>
      </>
    );
  };

  async function Auto() {
    await new Promise(function (s) {
      setTimeout(s, 1000);
    });
    document.querySelector("#button").click();

    await new Promise(function (s) {
      setTimeout(s, 1000);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Auto();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {Play()}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's a `Play` component inside `Play` component?

Comment: It's a React anti-pattern to declare React components inside another React component. They should be declared on their own. It's also not recommended to query the DOM to access DOMNodes, use an attached React ref for this.

Comment: Why do you use a `<button>` if all you want is to play a sound? there's the `AudioElement.play()` all you need is to create an in-memory `audio` element and play it. No button needed and silly `.click()` calls. Also, why not use the superior Svelte instead of React? ;)

Comment: tell me please how to do it? I dont know